# How to read a .csv data file separated by slash into matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

How can I read a .csv data file separated by slash (`'/'`) into matlab.
for example, I have a .csv file like below, how do I read it into matlab without having the values replaced by `NaN`?

> ```
> Apertures         
> Offset s    Shape   Inner Dia U/V   Ellipse Param a/b/c/d
> 0       0.152 / 0.0415  0.076 / 0.02075 / 0.076 / 0.02075
> 0       0.152 / 0.0387  0.076 / 0.01935 / 0.076 / 0.01935
> 0       0.152 / 0.0387  0.076 / 0.01935 / 0.076 / 0.01935
> ```

Comment: Your first and third columns doesn't seem to be separated from the others with a slash symbol but with a tab instead. You should use a consistent separator between columns, or do you want to use both slash and tab for column separation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dlmread` and specify the splash as delimiter.

Syntax:  M = dlmread(filename, delimiter)

Example:

```
dlmread('myfile.txt', '/')
```

If you have a header row with column names you can specify which row and column you want to start reading.

Syntax:  M = dlmread(filename,delimiter,R1,C1)

Example

```
dlmread('myfile.txt', '/', 1, 0)  % skip first row
```

**EDIT**: If your file data contains not only numbers but also text, then you can use `textscan` which will read the data into a cellarray, or `readtable` which will read your data into a table.

Example (suppose your file has 3 columns: integer, text, float):

Using textscan

```
fileID = fopen('/path/to/your/file.csv');
Data = textscan(fileID,'%d %s %f');
fclose(fileID);
```

Or using tables:

```
Data = readtable('/path/to/your/file.csv');
```

Comment: Thanks but am receiving error using 'dlmread', the original file is 3996*17 matrix with some columns containing text, empty space, splash separated data, etc.

Comment: If your file contains text is a complete different thing. then you cannot store the content in an array. Please update your question to make reference to that. I updated my answer to provide two different solutions to it.